Plotting Performance Diagram for a dataset with Python
I am analyzing some datasets. Okay, they are in this form:
| Products | POD | Successratio |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| CPC  | 0.85   | 0.4  |
| ARC  | 0.74   | 0.34  |
| TAM  | 0.65   | 0.28  |
| PER  | 0.80   | 0.35  |

I need to plot a performance diagram for a dataset like this as shown in the attached diagram. Something exactly similar[![Expectation(https://i.sstatic.net/55U6hUHO.png)]

"Let's say I have a Pandas Dataframe in the form" don't make us guess, provide a clear [mre]

Plotting the data like that in the image with matplotlib is like a pain in the head . One could do it but seaborn is generally useful for it.
After importing seaborn and pyplot, add your data in a python dictionary (remember to replace the string with your actual data ') .Now use pandas to create this as a data frame . Now for the scatters create a seaborn relational plot.
The main thing is rotate the axis to prevent it from overlapping the while plot , use plt.xticks with rotation argument or plot.axes.flat
for ax in plot.axes.flat:
    for label in ax.get_xticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(45)

Now run the code to get the plot
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = {'HRRR mem1 hrconus Performance': ['Your Data Here'],
        'HRRR mem2 hrconus Performance': ['Your Data Here'],
        'HRRR mem3 hrconus Performance': ['Your Data Here'],
        'HRRR mem4 hrconus Performance': ['Your Data Here'],
        'HRRR mem5 hrconus Performance': ['Your Data Here'],
        'HRRR mem6 hrconus Performance': ['Your data here'],
        'HRRR mem7 hrconus Performance': ['Your Daya Here'],
        'HRRR mem8 hrconus Performance': ['Your Data Here']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
sns.relplot(data=df)

plt.title("3Hr APCD , 18 HR Lead Conus")
plt.xlabel("Success Ratio")
plt.ylabel("Probability of Detection")

#Rotate x labels to prevent overlapping
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

Here is the output when your replace the data with np.random.rand
"3Hr APCD , 18 HR Lead Conus"
